# Azure AD app grants bearer token with a scope from a different AD app under the same tenant

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization

I have an **AD app(client id: xyz, scope: xyz_123)** and another **AD app(client id: abc, scope: abc_123)** under the **same tenant**.

---

Suppose my jwt token validation code in the service is something like

```
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                {
                    xyz,
                    xyz_123
                }
            };
```

So Now when I generate a bearer token with grant_type as client credentials and **client id: abc and the resource_id: xyz_123** and hit my service, the authentication is successful.

---

Is this expected behavior. Why is the AD app(client id: abc) granting a bearer token when hit with a resource/scope that it does not have(xyz_123). Do all the AD app instances under the same tenant have access to all its scopes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You must check token permissions to secure your API properly.

It used to be possible to do that over tenant boundaries, but now it's only possible within the tenant: https://joonasw.net/view/cross-tenant-token-attacks-now-harder-in-azure-ad.

You need to check any access token received by your app has at least one valid delegated / application permission: https://joonasw.net/view/always-check-token-permissions-in-aad-protected-api

Comment: There have not been any delegated permissions that were setup on either of the azure ad apps. 
As per your reply, if I just get to know the appid:url(resource id) of an azure ad app and my service uses its client id, it does not matter which azure ad app my service is bounded to, any azure ad app under the same tenant will be able to dispatch a working bearer token if just the appid:url is the same.

Is my understanding correct and why was this designed to be in such a way?

Comment: Then you should define some and check for them. Any app in your tenant can acquire a token for your API with client credentials flow. The token will be completely valid, except it won't contain any permissions unless they have been assigned. This is why they must be defined and checked.

Comment: Simplifying, We have azure ad apps A,B,C under the same tenant. If A has a scope xyz, I can request for a perfectly working bearer token with scope xyz with C as well which is validated properly on the service even when the audience is set to xyz and client credential is set that of A.

Do I need to keep the scope as a secret if I do not other people in my organisation to not gain access to the service by just hitting their azure ad with my scope??

Comment: Okay, let me try to explain what is possible if you do not check for token permissions in your API. Let's say you have tenant A. You have your API A registered there. Let's say I have an application registered in your tenant A, we will call it app B. Now, app B can acquire a token from tenant A for API A. It does not need to be assigned permissions to do this. The resulting token is otherwise valid, except it does not contain permissions (since we did not assign any). If I registered app C in my tenant B, I cannot get an access token for your API A from tenant A.

Comment: One possible attack scenario is: I register app C in my tenant B as a multi-tenant app. Then I trick one of the users in tenant A to use my app C. If they are able to consent, a service principal is created for app C in tenant A. This will then allow app C to get an access token for API A from tenant A! Assuming it knows the client id / app id URI of the API of course. I explain this in the first article I linked.